# Spanning a group in terms of traceless tensors

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In page 7 of the Physics paper [Decomposition of non-local light-cone operators
into harmonic operators of definite twist](https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1016/S0550-3213(99)00334-X) , it is said that

> However, for O(N,$\mathbb{C}$) and SO(N, $\mathbb{C}$) these representations, in general,
> are not irreducible. The reason is that taking the trace of a tensor commutes with
> the orthogonal transformations. Therefore, by Schur's Lemma, irreducible subspaces of
> SO(N, $\mathbb{C}$) are spanned by traceless tensors having definite symmetry class.

I don't understand how Schur's lemma, that basically states that an operator $A$ that commutes with the group operation is either $0$ or the identity, can lead to claim that traceless tensors span SO(N, $\mathbb{C}$). I know that traces are invariant under the action of said group, so in principle you would have both traces as irreps and traceless tensors.

My second question is that if those traceless tensors can be decomposed in irreps or not.

Comment: From what's written, it is hard to tell which representations they are working with: Are these just tensor products of pairs of irreducible representations? What's "definite symmetry class" is totally unclear. Likely, this is just a garbled discussion of the direct sum decompositions into irreps of irreducible representations of orthogonal groups, see for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representations_of_classical_Lie_groups#Construction_of_representations).